# How to view images on network?

Tags: network-shares, images, nas

Using Winfsp/sshfs, I have a network drive connected like so

\\location\path\

1. I'm able to open the location. 2. Windows Explorer is able to display previews of all the images. But
2. When I click on an image, Windows image viewer opens a blank image window.

If I copy the image to a local folder, it opens correctly and I can see the image.

Is there any way to make default Windows image viewer correctly open images on a network drive?

Running Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by winfsp.
Windows really doesn't like 3rd party network filesystems with all sorts of weird behavior as a consequence.

Why don't you setup a SMB share on your NAS in stead of trying to force Windows to try to emulate Linux/Unix behavior? That would be a lot simpler and will work as intended without any issues.

If SMB is not an option (I have no idea if you control the NAS) maybe NFS can be used instead. Even though NFS is also originally a Unix product Windows has good native support for NFS for quite a while now. (Since Windows 7 if I remember correctly.) The "Client for NFS" can be enabled in the Windows Features (using the old-style Control Panel, not in the new Features App).

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on an image go to Open With... and choose Windows Live Photo Gallery